# how to disable the back button in device by implement 1 function

Tags: android

i am trying to disable the back button in my device with the following code.
the code is working but i would like that the function that handle all the back button request in the fragments will derived from the Main Activity

this is the back button handler:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();

    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please navigate via the menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As i know you need to Override the onBackPressed() function of each activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to override `onBackPressed` function:

```
private boolean disabled = true;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!disabled) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

With this you can easy change `disable` flag and enable back button when needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     //leave it empty
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not the best idea to disable the back button as the user expects that button to perform some sort of back navigation. Now that being said, if you have a specific reason you can disable the back button by overriding the [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) at the activity level and not calling into super.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    executeAtAndroidOnBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        executeAtAndroidOnBackPressed();
    }
    return false;
}

protected void executeAtAndroidOnBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: i have a main activity that holds all the fragments but how can i use this method from the main activity in each fragment?

Comment: I will edit my answer. You should update your question to add this information.

Comment: and by that code which code i need to put in each fragment?

Comment: i try your code and added inside executeAtAndroidOnBackPressed() the line Toast.makeText(this,"back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG); but its not showing nothing its just disable the button with out show any message.

Comment: You should remove any back configuration at your fragments.

Comment: This code probably is deactivating the back button before of my implementation.

Comment: only the code that i declared in my question working for me but i don't know how to make it global for all the fragments.